# Seat Ibiza Electronic power control

Tags: electrical, seat-ibiza

I lease a Seat Ibiza 1.4 16V Stella and have an interesting problem.

After 6 months the EPS light will show up occasionally. It's been back to the garage a few times for the issue where they reset the computer and fix the car. They test drove the car and found no problems. When I got the car back and drove 5 to 10km the EPS light came on again. This has repeated three times already.

The ECU gives the error: Brake pedal switch.

Both of the switches (break-> ECU, make -> brake lights) have been replaced already. They even replaced the wiring.

The interesting/frustrating part is that the mechanic drove the car for 50-100km in between repairs without the EPS light ever showing.

Is this a known issue? What can be done to fix it? Is it possible that this fault is influenced by driving styles?

I'm an electrical engineer by trade and have a basic understanding of car mechanics.

Comment: System like these they use information from the ABS sensors at the wheels, did they check if those are clean and in good working condition?

Comment: If it's a brake pedal issue and all switches and wires have been replaced, I see the last possibility only in ECU pin.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I'm going to contact the garage again Monday.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: The car is a rental. The rental service knows about the problem and said I shouldn't worry. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @JWRM22 - I don't have a solution for you. I was hoping you had one for us! :o) In my world we'd call this OBE (Overcome By Events).

Answer (score -1):

The cruise control shutoff switch is usually part of the brake switch. Back in the old days, it was 2 different switches, but now most of them are incorporated into one switch but if you've changed it, then the only other brake switches are the one on your master cylinder to let you know if your fluid level is low, the emergency brake switch that lets you know it engauged and there might be some sort of brake switch on the anti-lock unit. Now as your disc brakes wear away, more and more fluid stays down in the calipers, so it might appear the level is down in your master cylinder for that reason, so if you add any fluid, you only want to add enough to make your brake light go off because when you put new brake shoes on it, you compress the calipers and the fluid goes back up into the master cylinder and if you put to much in when you're trying to make the light go off, then it will be all over the floor when you compress the calipers, but that's only if the RED brake light is staying on, not if the check engine light is giving you a brake code.